How can I get chatGPT to generate consistent outputs?
I am using the GPT-4o API to process scanned book pages and dump the text into a JSON format. This works reasonably well, but I notice that every time I run the script (on the same image), I get a differently formatted output. Ideally it would produce consistent results, because I want to do this on a series of pages, and I would like each one to be formatted the same way.
How can I get GPT-4o to produce consistent results? Do I need to modify the temperature parameter? If so, how? And would this affect the quality of the OCR results?


Do I need to modify the temperature parameter? If so, how?

Temperature=0, and set a seed.

And would this affect the quality of the OCR results?

Afaik, no.
